# How to bind on UI Element?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have the same porblem every time. I want to create a custom control with "UIElement" DependencyProperty. So, on which element in XAML I could create binding to this DependencyProperty?

Canvas's Children property says that it's impossible, Grid even don't have "Children" property in XAML and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: could you please elaborate it more? with some code.

Comment: Don't know what to elaborate. I want to create a control with DependencyProperty typeof "UIElement". And I need to create Binding in XAML (of same control) on this UIElement. How can I do it?

Comment: Another word. Which element allows UIElement (FrameworkElement) binding?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but javascript knockout works well with UI bindings:

http://knockoutjs.com/

Also take a look at handlebars:

http://handlebarsjs.com/

Hope that helps

Comment: I need WPF control-container on which I could create binding to UIElement... What for javaScript?

Comment: You can use javascript and xaml together.